# Multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

How I can extend my class with methods from two different classes?

For example, given two classes:

- `timed_events` (with methods: setMaxTimeLimit, etc)
- `protected_events` (with methods: setPublic, setPrivate)

I want to create classes `ChatMessagesList` which is a `protected_events` and `timed_events` and `ActionEventsList` which is a `timed_events`.

Can I create classes that include `timed_events` and `protected_events`? I have many classes with sample functionality, but I don't want repeat my code. With one-parent inheritance I can't solve this problem.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should have looked through the related questions before posting. This seems to be a valid way to get class C to inherit from classes A and B:

```
class A(object):
    # stuff for A goes here
class B(object):
    # stuff for B goes here
class C(A, B):
    # stuff for C should come from A and B.
```

As Dek points out in the comment, the Python documentation already has a page about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChatMessagesList(protected_events, timed_events):
    ....


class ActionEventsList(timed_events):
    ....
```